# c# wpf - windows forms host border color

Tags: wpf, border

I'm creating a windows forms host to display a dashboard.

It's displaying a border, how do I remove it?

currently have:

Creating a grid.

```
<Grid Name="winForms" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Binding it to dashboard.

```
// Create the interop host control.
            System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
                new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
            this.winForms.Children.Add(host);



            //THIS SHIT SHOWS A DESIGNER LOL
            System.Windows.Forms.UserControl uc = new System.Windows.Forms.UserControl();
            DevExpress.DashboardWin.DashboardViewer dd = new DevExpress.DashboardWin.DashboardViewer();

            dd.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;


            dd.DashboardSource = "DashboardFiles/KPI.xml";
            uc.Controls.Add(dd);
            dd.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            //dd.CreateRibbon();
            host.Child = uc;
```

I thought the border belonged to the dashboard viewer but it does not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the **FormBorderStyle** property in the design view or else you can set the Property **FormBorderStyle** in code behind like this :

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```